# How to specify the schema prefix of a table in ANSI SQL?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

In order to SELECT from a table, the table name is specified in ANSI SQL as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM "My Table"
```

I was wondering if there is an ANSI SQL rule on how to specify the schema name of a table. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM "My Schema"."My Table"
```

On SQL Server, it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM [My Schema].[My Table]
```

but this is obviously not ANSI SQL but T-SQL.

Comment: Your second statement is correct. A schema name is an identifier just like a table, column or catalog name. The same rules apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Standard SQL way is

```
SELECT * FROM "My Schema"."My Table"
```

Caution: Double quoted names are case sensitive, so they're are not really recommended.

Comment: The case sensitivity of quoted identifiers will vary by RDBMS and the settings used.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: the question is about ANSI SQL, and the SQL standard is pretty clear about this. _If_ an identifier is quoted, it **is** case sensitive.